# How do i create a stack of multidimentional arrays

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, multidimensional-array, stack

i know how to create a stack of vectors or int ,etc. But i dont know how to create a stack of a multidimentional arrays t[n][n] . Whats the way to implement it? 
this is my actual implementation which its not working.

```
char map[20][20];
stack<map> soluciones;
```

Edit:

I think due my english most of you didnt undestand my question. Imagine i got some kind of a Game map. I am saving each multidimentional array on the stack. Thats my objective saving the map on a stack

Edit 2: im using Visual Studio 2010 Windows form application

Comment: Use `std::array<std::array<char, 20>, 20>` if your compiler supports it. Otherwise, you might have `std::tr1::array` available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code example, you use `map` (the name of your variable) in place of where a type name must stand (in `stack<map>` template instantiation). However, it won't work, not even if you use the proper type name (in this case you'd have to use typedef, e.g. `typedef char TwoDimCharArray[20][20]` and then try `std::stack<TwoDimCharArray>`:

There is still the problem that arrays don't have a default constructor (which `std::stack` expects); therefore, `std::stack` cannot be made to directly contain arrays; you'd have to wrap the array inside a class or struct (which can have a default constructor), e.g.:

```
class TwoDimCharArray
{
public:
    // omit if there's nothing to initialize in map, then the
    // compiler-generated constructor will be used
    TwoDimCharArray()
    {
        // ... initalize map values
    }
    // ... provide access methods to map
private:
    char map[20][20];
};

std::stack<TwoDimCharArray> soluciones;
```

Or use [`Boost.Array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/array.html) or C++11 `std::array` stuff! If these are available, they are definitely the better and easier choice!

Answer (score 3):

I guess you should define a proper class for the game map. Then the stack of game maps is not a problem.

```
class GameMap {
public:
...
private:
  char map_[1000][1000];
};
```

Then it wont matter for the stack how you allocate and manage the map data. E.g.

```
typedef std::stack<GameMap> GameMapStack;
```

Answer (score 2):

Ddefine a wrapper class for multidimentional arrays like this:

```
template <class T, int X, int Y>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    T array[X][Y];
}
```

Then use `stack<Wrapper<char, 20, 20> >`

Answer (score 1):

First create structure and then define an empty multidimensional char array. then close structure and after thar write push and pop operations.